# I am trying to retrieve data and display it in a page in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Following is my show page code to display the data:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div 
                    class="panel-heading">subnet_behind_clients
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="{{ url('/subnet_behind_clients') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>client_id</th>
                                        <th>ip_address</th>
                                        <th>netmask</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($clients as $client)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $client->ip_address }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $client->netmask }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger " data-target = "del/{{$client->id}}">Delete</button> 
                                        </td>
                                    /tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and following is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Subnet_behind_client;
use DateTime;

class Subnet_Behind_ClientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

                /* $datas = Subnet_behind_client::all();
                $data = $datas->first();*/

                $data = Subnet_behind_client::first();

                return view('subnet_behind_clients',compact('data'));
    }


    public function create(Request $request)
    {

                $data = new Subnet_behind_client;
                return view('subnet_behind_clients1',compact('data'));
                Subnet_behind_client::create([
                    //'client_id' => $request->input('1'),
                    'ip_address' => $request->input('ip_address'),
                    'netmask' => $request->input('netmask'),
                ]);
    }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
                $datas = Subnet_behind_client::all();
                $data = new Subnet_behind_client;
                $data->client_id = '1';
                $data->ip_address = $request->ip_address;
                $data->netmask = $request->netmask;

                $data->save();
                return back();

    }

    public function show(Request $request)
    {
                $clients = Subnet_behind_client::all();
                return view('view2',compact('clients'));
    }
            public function destroy($id)
            {
                $clients = Subnet_behind_client::findOrFail( $id );
                $clients->delete();
                return view('view2',compact('clients'));
            }  
    }
```

plz let me know what is wrong for the code in foreach
the first part is the view page
and the second page is for the controller part
I made edited my earlier post. Plz take a look and let me know.

Comment: what is the error you got??

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Subnet_behind_clients' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller should look like this:

```
use App\Subnet_behind_clients;

public function show(Request $request)
{
    $clients = Subnet_behind_clients::all();
    return view('view2', compact('clients '));
}
```

And view:

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    ....
@endforeach
```

Never use Eloquent or Query Builder in views.

Comment: yes that what RRp suggested. But getting error with that: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (View: /var/www/html/vsecnet/resources/views/view2.blade.php)

Comment: You're probably still getting the error because you're using this class in view too. So remove any data related code from view and it should work just fine.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: It's the same `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Subnet_behind_clients' not found` error? If so, please post somewhere full view and controller code please.

Comment: shall i post the complete code here by editing or someplace else

Comment: Looks fine except there is no closing `form` tag. I don't think you can get error with `App\Http\Controllers\Subnet_behind_clients` namespace with this code. Try to run `composer dumpauto` command and check if you're using `Subnet_behind_clients` somewhere else.

Comment: i know the place fro where error is coming,its <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>    what i should give instead to this

Comment: If you see the error which says about error in the view, usually it gives you a line from compiled view. So, the error could be in cached view which still uses `@foreach (Subnet_behind_client::all() as $data)`. Try to run `php artisan view:clear` or manually delete all `php` files in `storage/framework/views` directory.

Comment: inaddition to the earlier one how can we delete a particular data from the view page

Comment: @gaan10 I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question. What exactly data you want to delete from view?

Comment: actually now since data are there in the view i want to delete a particular data from the view page ,i have modified the view and controller but unable to delete a particular records plz have a look at the modififed code

Answer (score 0):

try this

controller

```
use App\Subnet_behind_clients

public function show(Request $request)
{
     $datas = Subnet_behind_clients::all();
     return view('view2',compact('datas'));
}
```

view

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
<tr>

    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>

    <td>{{ $data->ip_address }}</td>

    <td>{{ $data->netmask }}</td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Comment: its showing: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (View: /var/www/html/vsecnet/resources/views/view2.blade.php)

Comment: did u miss @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

if you got `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Subnet_behind_clients' not found`

use `use App\Subnet_behind_clients`(namespace of model) after namespace in controller

you forgot to add namespance of model in controller

Comment: but not seems to be, check it again

Comment: sorry the model name was Subnet_behind_client and not Subnet_behind_clients.,that  i corrected but its showing again error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (View: /var/www/html/vsecnet/resources/views/view2.blade.php)......i did exactly u said

Comment: check if you missed any '@endif' or '@endforeach' or '}'
 this error comes in such situations

Comment: didn't miss anything

Comment: i know the place fro where error is coming,its <td>{{ ++$i }}</td> what i should give instead to this